# give each loop 30 sec execution time

Tags: php

I have my application hosted in Siteground, in a shared host. I have build a cron job that executes a php file every night. The problem is that that file contains a main loop that executes the code, 85 times. More precisely, i take arrays of data and manipulate them. This is done 85 times. 
Something like this:

```
<?php
$main_array = array("//85 elements");
foreach ($main_array as $var){

 $array1 = array ("//a lot of data");
//manipulate array1

}
?>
```

Since there are many manipulations of the taken data, it takes 2 minutes and 5' to completely execute. By any chance.. is there a way  to set the execution time 30 sec for each "foreach" loop?? 
I can't move to dedicated host, so i need to figure something else out..

Thanks in advace

Comment: Show your code. I think that we can help with performance.

Comment: what should be happen after 30 seconds? Just skip the script?

Comment: If the manipulation of the arrays is done in separation of each other you can try to split `$main_array` into smaller ones and run the cron job five times processing each chunk at a time.

Comment: @MichalTrojanowski i thought about that before but it works for only two loops at a time. It works Ok with no more than 2 elements in main_array.If i put more elements in the main_array the result gets crazy. And i can't just make 42 cron jobs..

Answer (score 3):

Use microtime() to evaluate running time of each loop.

```
<?php
$main_array = array("//85 elements");
foreach ($main_array as $var){
  $time_start = microtime(true);
  $array1 = array ("//a lot of data");
  //manipulate array1
  $time_end = microtime(true);
  $time = $time_end - $time_start;
  //check sometimes in your script whether execution time is reached
  if($time > 30){
    break; //or continue; which you want
  }
}
?>
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.microtime.php

But the execution time is really long, what is sour script calculating? Maybe there are much more effective ways to do so...

Comment: In thick lines,my script does smth like this: for each user (main_array(user1, user2..user85);) -> get data from server -> put it in an array -> remove jumps (if array('3','4,'99',3); '99'  is considered a jump) -> normalize data -> again remove jumps ->insert in db.  But there are a lot of data to be manipulated. Only one loop (one user) takes 6 sec to execute.

Comment: could you post the whole script or at least the part which takes such long time? (btw. sorry for considering you male, I didn't read your name)

Comment: I tried your solution, but it didn't work out :( I would post my code but it's too long. If i post it as my own answer..would you guys still be able to comment? ..i'm not very sure how stackover works :/

Comment: Stackoverflow is particulary like a Wiki so just edit your Question. Posting an answer is just used for solutions for the problem. If the code is too long try to find out the parts taking too much time and/or poste the code linked to an external hoster like pastebin or github.

Comment: part of the variables are in my native language, but most of the code is in english and so are the comments. https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B51Lyn41Ugszd0FrNE5JcFhpa3c/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 1):

```
set_time_limit(30); //Enter the value in seconds
```

Check [set_time_limit()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-time-limit.php) in php

Answer (score 1):

Make use of the `set_time_limit(0);` function on the top of your code.

**[PHP Manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/info.configuration.php#ini.max-execution-time)**

> This sets the maximum time in seconds a script is allowed to run
>   before it is terminated by the parser. This helps prevent poorly
>   written scripts from tying up the server. The default setting is 30.
>   When running PHP from the command line the default setting is 0.
>
> The maximum execution time is not affected by system calls, stream
>   operations etc. Please see the set_time_limit() function for more
>   details.
>
> You can not change this setting with ini_set() when running in safe
>   mode. The only workaround is to turn off safe mode or by changing the
>   time limit in the php.ini.
>
> Your web server can have other timeout configurations that may also
>   interrupt PHP execution. Apache has a Timeout directive and IIS has a
>   CGI timeout function. Both default to 300 seconds. See your web server
>   documentation for specific details.

Comment: `set_time_limit` will probably be disabled on a shared host which has a strict resource policy.

Comment: this set's time limit to whole script execution but he want's to set it just for each loop i think...

Comment: @abimelex you're right. I want to set it for each loop. Not entire script. ..oh and by the way i am a "she" :)

Answer (score 0):

```
set_time_limit(999); // some number you want
```

Try this.